# Can't ssh into Raspberry pi running raspberry pi os 64 bit lite

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, putty, boot

TLDR - Raspberry pi 3 B, can't use ssh, I have tried many solutions listed below and more, any suggestions? hostname -I command returns a blank line

I cant use ssh, I have tried everything, sudo raspi-config, systemctl start / enable, creating an ssh file in the boot folder, setting the locale settings, I checked that the pi is connected to wifi and that my pc is connected to the same wifi, I think the most notable issue is that hostname -I returns a blank line. I even went so far as to use arp -a and just try to ssh into every ip and see what sticks but none of them worked. I have considered that maybe the computer itself is compromised in some way but it's in a solid case and it was previously running octo-pi with no issues. Anything helps so if you have an idea that I listed, I might have done it wrong so please suggest away.

Comment: This type of question is gonna get a better response at one of these sites: unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com (using the same profile / user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have a file called `ssh` (without any extensions) in the `/boot` directory of the OS on your microSD card. This missing file is usually the issue.

If this does not exist, create one within the `/boot` dir and restart your pi.

```
sudo -i
cd /boot
touch ssh
chown root:root ssh
chmod 755 ssh
shutdown -r now
```

The OS will find the file on bootup and activate SSH.

Comment: I did that and hostname -I still returns an empty line, entering the hostname on Putty returns "Host does not exist", I tried manually turning on ssh with raspi-config and repeated, no change, and thank you for your help by the way, it is appreciated

Comment: I used the ip address from ifconfig and got a connection refused on putty

Comment: Carry out ``` hostnamectl``` and check that a value is returned for ```Static hostname```.

Comment: yeah, that returns the hostname I setup

Comment: does the ```ssh``` have owner permissions as ```root:root``` and file permissions with at least ```755```

Comment: Also, this type of question is gonna get a better response at one of these sites: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ (using the same profile / user)

Comment: also - run ```sudo apt-get install ssh``` to get latest ssh package

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, also sorry but, how do I check the owner permissions?

Comment: ```ls -altr /boot/ssh``` and it should show at least ```-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root```

Comment: It says "cannot access, no such directory" so you might be on to something here, also I checked and the ssh package is up to date

Comment: So, to anybody who's looking to this in the future, I just rebooted and then switched the wifi using the sudo raspi-config command, then used hostname -I and it worked, so double check for any network related issues